# Why change feed lag estimator showing lag in millions?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

I am working on cosmos db change feed for a real time project. we are running our webjobs in azure app service with P3V2 specification. there are multiple webjobs running using change feed. So to monitor the processes we have used the change feed lag estimator for monitoring record lags. the implementation is according to following document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-use-change-feed-estimator

For one of the webjob in the .net core code we have put a delay of 10 mins using await Task.delay() function. for that specific webjob we are getting estimation in millions even though the records which we are processing are not more than 100.
This is kind of uncertain behavior we are observing. can anyone help to find the exact reason?

Answer (score 1):

Is the Estimator matching a processor that is currently running and processing documents? Normally what you describe matches a scenario where the Processor is not running/never ran or never completed a successful run on some of the leases.

You can use the detailed estimation to understand how the lag is distributed across leases: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-use-change-feed-estimator#as-an-on-demand-detailed-estimation